# MySQL - Search into a custom Column

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

I want to run a MySQL query like this-

```
 SELECT country_ID*2/id*3.159 as my_id
 FROM `state`
 WHERE my_id>2;
```

When I run it, I am getting an error like this-

> 1054 - Unknown column 'my_id' in 'where clause'

Is there any alternative solution to search in my new created virtual column **my_id** ?

---

Actually I am trying to make a search in **[Laravel Query Builder](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries)** like this-

```
  DB::table(    'project')->select( 'project.id as id',
                                    'project.completion_date as completion_date',
                                     DB::raw('FORMAT(project.total_cost_to_dispose - project.actual_cost_dispose, 2) as disposal_savings')
                                   )
                            ->where(disposal_savings>100);
```

Can I do it?

If not, then what is the solution in Laravel or MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use complete condition again in where clause as:

```
  DB::table(    'project')->select( 'project.id as id',
                                    'project.completion_date as completion_date',
                                     DB::raw('FORMAT(project.total_cost_to_dispose - project.actual_cost_dispose, 2) as disposal_savings')
                                   )
                            ->where FORMAT(project.total_cost_to_dispose - project.actual_cost_dispose, 2) > 100;
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot refer in `WHERE` to aliases, use instead:

```
SELECT country_ID*2/id*3.159 as my_id 
FROM `state`
WHERE (country_ID*2/id*3.159)>2;
```

or use subquery:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM
(
   SELECT country_ID*2/id*3.159 as my_id 
   FROM `state`
) as t
WHERE t.my_id>2
```

[Simplified logical query processing](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20724.all-at-once-operations-in-t-sql.aspx), `SELECT` is almost last, so `WHERE` doesn't know about `my_id` alias:

[image]

<sup>Image source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20724.all-at-once-operations-in-t-sql.aspx</sup>