# Postgresql WHERE with age() function

Tags: sql, postgresql, alias

I'm pretty sure this has been asked before but I am struggling to get the correct syntax for a table containing data like

```
id  date        type                                    report  item_id
1   2018-11-07  Veröffentlichung des 9-Monats-Berichtes TRUE    16
2   2018-11-06  Veröffentlichung des 9-Monats-Berichtes TRUE    17
3   2019-03-07  Veröffentlichung des Jahresberichtes    TRUE    17
4   2019-05-10  Bericht zum 1. Quartal                  TRUE    17
```

The query I am trying to formulate is

```
SELECT date, AGE(now(), date) as t1
FROM dates
WHERE t1 > 0
```

Meaning I am only looking for values in the past.
However, I get an error

> ERROR:  column "t1" does not exist

(of course, it is an alias). Does Postgresql not support aliases here?

Comment: also `t1` (interval) is not comparable with `0` (number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot refer to alias in `WHERE` condition, because logically `WHERE` is executed before `SELECT`.

You could use subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT date, AGE(now(), date) as t1
      FROM dates) sub
WHERE sub.t1 > interval '0::seconds';
```

Or [`LATERAL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL)(my favourite way):

```
SELECT date, s.t1
FROM dates
,LATERAL (SELECT AGE(now(), date) as t1) AS s
WHERE s.t1 > interval '0::seconds';
```

Or repeat expression(violates [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)):

```
SELECT date, AGE(now(), date) as t1
FROM dates
WHERE AGE(now(), date) > interval '0::seconds';
```

As for calculating `AGE` you don't really need it, because you could rewrite it as `date > now()`.

---

Related articles:

[PostgreSQL: using a calculated column in the same query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840228/postgresql-using-a-calculated-column-in-the-same-query/36530228#36530228)

[MySQL - Search into a custom Column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32624840/5070879)

[Why do “linq to sql” queries starts with the FROM keyword unlike regular SQL queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32668427/why-do-linq-to-sql-queries-starts-with-the-from-keyword-unlike-regular-sql-que/32668470#32668470)

Comment: don't use a subquery. CTEs are optimisation fences and that doesn't help here.

Comment: COuld you elaborate on `LATERAL` a bit? And I'm indeed always trying to be `DRY`.

Comment: Now I get `HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: @Jan Sure, updated my answer

Comment: @LukaszSzozda: Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you're in a hurry and have an (ordered) index on date don't do that.

Because this query can use the index giving a massive gain in performance at only a slight investment in coding effort.

```
SELECT date, AGE(now(), date) AS t1
FROM dates
WHERE date > now();
```

I say `now()`, because you did, but perhaps you want `CURRENT_DATE` instead

To create a suitable index do

`create index dates_date on dates(date);`

Comment: Thanks for the answer - how would I change the table to have an index?